# In NodeJS, how to correctly create a docx file download function via a REST endpoint?

Tags: node.js, axios, nuxt.js, fs

I've been trying to create a function that lets client download a docx file from NodeJS server.
With some research, I could successfully download the file but was unable to open it.
Below is my try:

- On Server, I have a post endpoint:

```
router.post("/download", async (req, res, next) => {
  // declare: _filepath, _filename
  ...
  let stream = fs.createReadStream(_filepath, { bufferSize: 64 * 1024 })
  res.setHeader('Content-Disposition', `attachment; filename=${_filename}`);
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessing');
  stream.pipe(res)
  ...
  // handle stream events: error, close
})
```

- At Client, I have:

```
// declare _reqBody
...
await axios.$post("/download", _reqBody, { responseType: 'blob' })
  .then(response => {
    let blob = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessing' });
    let url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    let a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = url;
    a.download = 'myfile.docx';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
  });
```

Since this code makes me available to download but the file seemed to be corrupted, could someone give me a hand on this?
From my googling, the response should look like
[expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPG22.png)
but what I actually get was
[actual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoDdR.png)

Comment: Set the `Content-Type` to "application/octet-stream" & remove the `bufferSize` from `fs.createReadStream`. Try to Download the file via postman or plain http request (browser) from the node server and then try to open it. If it works, just do request on the file url client side. BTW: Download should be a `GET` and not post...

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer @Marc. I would submit a significant load of request body so I use `POST`.